# How to document the post body using flask-ReSTplus?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

[image: insert user data]

How to document the input body that is expected to be posted in the `value` field to appear so that the user knows what to post? the following data is used currently:

```
{
 "customer_id": "",
 "service_id": "",
 "customer_name": "",
 "site_name": "",
 "service_type": ""
}
```

can we populate the value by default with the above json?

Code:

```
post_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
post_parser.add_argument('database',  type=list, help='user data', location='json')

@ns_database.route('/insert_user')
class database(Resource):
@ns_database.expect(post_parser)
def post(self):
    """insert data"""
    json_data = request.json
    customer_id = json_data['customer_id']
    service_id = json_data['service_id']
    customer_name = json_data['customer_name']
    site_name = json_data['site_name']
    service_type = json_data['service_type']
```

Comment: You want text to appear as placeholder text _inside_ the textbox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved it (partially) using the following model

```
""" Model for documenting the API"""

insert_user_data = ns_database.model(
    "Insert_user_data",
    {
        "customer_id": fields.String(description="cust ID", required=True),
        "service_id": fields.String(description="service ID", required=True),
        "customer_name": fields.String(description="Customer1", required=True),
        "site_name": fields.String(description="site", required=True),
        "service_type": fields.String(description="service", required=True),
    },
)


@ns_database.route("/insert_user")
class database(Resource):
    @ns_database.expect(insert_user_data)
    def post(self):
        """insert data"""
        json_data = request.json
        customer_id = json_data["customer_id"]
        service_id = json_data["service_id"]
        customer_name = json_data["customer_name"]
        site_name = json_data["site_name"]
        service_type = json_data["service_type"]
```

now the API shows model for data input and an example

[image: solved]

Comment: I believe if you get rid of the `RequestParser.add_argument` code that you aren't showing above, then Swagger UI will generate input fields for each of your API model fields.

Comment: @dmulter even if there was no model and without `@api.expect(model)`  just removing the `RequestParser.add_argument` will solve it is what you mean or?

Comment: I meant that you only need the model definition along with `@api.expect(model)` to generate correct Swagger UI. You should not need the `RequestParser.add_argument` code. That's what is creating the `payload` parameter in the UI.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that and posted the answer :) thank you

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using a Flask template to return the `/database/insert_user` webpage, you could simply make the variable containing database information (customer_id, etc) accessible to where `render_template` is called, then pass the variable on to it.

For example if you wanted to pass the customer_id variable:

```
return render_template("insert_user.html", 
x=customer_id)
```

assuming `insert_user.html` is your template file you can then place the data where ever you want it using `{{ x }}`

Comment: The intention is to build an API but not rendering web pages. The above image is a part of the swagger documentation for the same API

Comment: Alright, but then I'm confused as to what you are asking

Comment: Like the answer I have written, I am expecting