# flask-restplus POST marshall input model that is different from response model

Tags: python, flask, model, marshalling, flask-restplus

I am building an api with flask_restplus. How the user gets/gives the data, is different of how is defined in my Models. This was easily solved with response marshalling https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html#renaming-attributes

As I see it, the decorator `@marshal_with()` marshals the output response, but not the input (at least if the input and output models are different).

I was able to "rename" the input given by the user in a `get` calls by using the `parser = reqparse.RequestParser()` and `parser.add_argument()`, because the `parser.parse_args()` also does the "renaming". The problem comes to the `post` calls:

For the `post` calls, I cannot use the `reqparse` because the swagger documentation does not look well ([How to document the post body using flask-ReSTplus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039018/how-to-document-the-post-body-using-flask-restplus)). 
Therefore I use a `@expect()` with the model I expect, but the `expect` does not rename the input json (simply validates). So what I have to end up doing is creating an additional Model and use `marshal_with(api.payload)` before managing the data. I however find it quite dirty because I need 3 models for one post call:
`ModelResponse`
`ModelExpected`
`ModelRename`

### Example

Let me put it in an example: in the internal system I call the fields as `user_name` and `user_age` but the client gets/gives the fields as `name` and `age`, then I have to:

```py
# define the response model (includes the user id)
UserResponse = api.model("userResponse",
                           {
                            "name": fields.String(description="name of the user", attribute="user_name", required=True),
                            "age": fields.String(description="age of the user", attribute="user_age"),
                            "user_id": fields.String(description="User ID", required=True, attribute="user_id")
                           }

# define the expected model (to validate the input)
UserExpectPost = api.model("userExpectPost",
                             {
                               "name": fields.String(description="name of the user", attribute="user_name", required=True),
                               "age": fields.String(description="age of the user", required=True, attribute="user_age")
                             }
# define the model again, reverse from UserExpectPost (to rename the input attributes)
UserPostRename = api.model("userPostRename",
                             {
                               "user_name": fields.String(description="name of the user", attribute="name", required=True),
                               "user_age": fields.String(description="age of the user", required=True, attribute="age")
                             }


class Users(Resource):
   @api.marshal_with(UserResponse)
   @api.expect(UserExpectPost)
   def post(self):
      data = marshal(api.payload, UserPostRename)
      # do stuff 
      return # return whatever will be marshalled with UserResponse
```

#### Question

So, the question is, is there a way that I can do it with just 2 models? (just responseModel and inputModel). I would need something like the `expect()` but that also renames the attributes from the payload.

Comment: don't use this `data = marshal(api.payload, UserPostRename)`, it converts what is in your payload into what response should look like. for data use `data = api.payload`

Comment: I need api.payload to be marshaled as UserPostRename model.. that's why I am marshaling. The response is marshaled with UserResponse model...